SF/horror short story about a man who is chosen in a government lottery to look after a prison silo
I read a short story some time ago, and I can't recall the title or the author. I've asked AI, but it... Isn't helpful. (But I'm grateful to our robot overlords for their attempts. Honestly.)
The story is about a man who is chosen in a government lottery to look after a prison silo. There are several of these silos in the country, and they basically hold living people in a HUGE pit. There's a control room where the wardens can watch the pit of squirming, screaming people. It's horrific.
Prisoners are brought regularly to this place and he has to extend a gangplank and push the prisoners off, into the pit of writhing, naked people. During the course of his stewardship, the man has to fight off an invasion of citizens who are revolting against the government.
At the end of the story, he has done a great job, but the government still pushes him into the pit of the silo. He asks not to be blindfolded or handcuffed, so he can experience the whole thing.
Does anyone recognise this story?

Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? And did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

It was in an anthology, I believe.... In digital form, because I remember reading it on my phone. I read it late last year, but I think it was written before the turn of this century.

Hmmm. I read a short horror story - print, not digital - from early 2000s that told a similar story but from the perspective of the people in the pit. Just these bodies falling from the sky and piling up endlessly. Very horrific. I wonder if it's related.

Omigosh, I would love to read that! Do you remember the title? Author?
